# How to render json data in frontend in magento?

Tags: json, magento

I am having a action method in a controller as

```
    public function ajaxAction()
    {   
        $this->loadLayout(false);   
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

I want to render this using the json  in frontend.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function ajaxAction()
    {  
         $arrayData = array('name'=>'xyz','age'=>'18');
         //Json Encode an Array in Magento
         echo $json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($arrayData);
         return;

        //Json Decode in Magento
       //$array = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($jsonString); 
    }
```

for your reference ajax call should be

```
new Ajax.Request({
    url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/controller/ajax')",//change your url here
    method: 'Post',
    dataType: "json",
    parameters: {parameter1: 'value1', parameter2: 'value2'}
    onComplete: function(data){
         var json = $.parseJSON(data); // create an object with the key of the array
       alert(json); //it will alert controller data
    }
});
```

Comment: what about $this->loadLayout(false);  $this->renderLayout(); Do I need to include this in array? I am not getting what you said.

Comment: no it is used for rendering page layout so you don't need to include $this->loadLayout(false); $this->renderLayout();

Answer (score 2):

you can  use

```
 public function datajsonAction()
    {  
         $arrayData = array('name'=>'xyz','age'=>'18');

          $$result = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($arrayData);





 $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
   }
```

and

```
new Ajax.Request({
    url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('test/mycontroller/datajson')",//change your url here
    method: 'Post',
    dataType: "json",
    parameters: {parameter1: 'value1', parameter2: 'value2'}
    onComplete: function(data){
         var json = $.parseJSON(data); // create an object with the key of the array
       alert(json); //it will alert controller data
    }
});
```